# Inserting values of checkbox back to form from local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am getting two values of checkbox one is always false with type hidden. I created a local storage and where I stored value of checkbox. I want to put values back into my form from local storage. Can somebody please help me with that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  InitalizeCache(GetKey());
});



function GetKey() {
  var key = "local";
  return key;
}

function CacheSpikeData() {
  var form = $("#application-form").serializeArray();
  CacheData(form, GetKey());
}




function InitalizeCache(key) {
  window.onload = function() {
    RecoverFormFromLocalStorage(key);
  }
}



function RecoverFormFromLocalStorage(key) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(key) !== null) {
    var recover = confirm("You have some unsaved changes. Do you want to continue from where you left? ");
    if (recover == true) {
      RecoverFormFromLocalStorage2(key);
      return true;
    } else {
      clearLocalStorage(key);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function ShowSpikeData() {
  alert(localStorage.getItem(GetKey()));
}

function LoadSpikeData() {
  RecoverFormFromLocalStorage2(GetKey());
}




function clearLocalStorage(key) {
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
}


function CacheData(jsoNform, key) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(jsoNform));
}

function RecoverFormFromLocalStorage2(key) {
  var cache = localStorage.getItem(key);
  var record = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));


  if (cache !== null) {
    $("#application-form *").filter(':input').each(function() {
      if (this.type != "hidden") {

        var cache = localStorage.getItem(key);
        var record = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        var cacheValue = $(record).find("Name=MyStringValue");
        this.value = cacheValue;
        alert(this.name + this.hidden);
      }
    });


  }

}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>View - NumberFormattingSample</title>

    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css">
    
    
    
</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="container body-content">
        
<h2>View</h2>

<form id="application-form" action="/Test/EditCheckbox" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestClass</h4>
        <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="MyStringValue">MyStringValue</label>      
        <div class="col-md-10">
          
                <input id="MyStringValue" name="MyStringValue" value="" aria-invalid="false" class="valid" type="text">           
          
        </div> 
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="MyValue4">MyValue4</label>      
            <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The MyValue4 field is required." id="MyValue4" name="MyValue4" value="true" type="checkbox">           
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="MyValue5">MyValue5</label>
            
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The MyValue5 field is required." id="MyValue5" name="MyValue5" value="true" type="checkbox">           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
<select>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option1</option>
  </select>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input value="Cache" type=button class="btn btn-default valid" onclick="CacheSpikeData()" aria-invalid="false">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input value="Show" type=button class="btn btn-default valid" onclick="ShowSpikeData()" aria-invalid="false">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input value="Load" type=button class="btn btn-default valid" onclick="LoadSpikeData()" aria-invalid="false">
            </div>
        </div>
  
    </div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="CfDJ8PubzbxcXzVMruNKDy4pjvN4hXQ65h4QOkv7uDsWo6fZ2L-XoEq_2ECU5X_vbG2E-06P5vqKof167EUuW9eWazRso-6D-lG8e74rUHikoOhsA_BVeWl4vx3OeutanaJtjbzs8RIpp4WuS74wbuf-5E0" type="hidden"><input name="MyValue4" value="false" type="hidden"><input name="MyValue5" value="false" type="hidden"></form>

<div>
    <a href="/Test">Back to List</a>
</div>


        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>© 2017 - NumberFormattingSample</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    
        <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=EWaMeWsJBYWmL2g_KkgXZQ5nPe-a3Ichp0LEgzXczKo"></script>
    
    

    

    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


    <script src="/js/Caching.js"></script>



</body></html>
```

I am simply trying to insert values back to form without deleting the hidden value of checkbox, but picking up the current value.

[image]

Comment: your html doesn't seem right to me. can't find hidden type of input?

Comment: "I am simply trying to insert values back to form without deleting the hidden value of checkbox, but picking up the current value." I don't understand this part. You said the hidden box is always false with type hidden(begging the question why you have it to begin with) but what does repopulating data have to do with deleting the hidden value?

Comment: I have added an image which has the hidden value as well.... I dont have them in code but they are appearing because of checkbox

Comment: @zfrisch- My main task is to insert values back from local storage to form but when I try to do that checkboxes always get false value even when they are true. That is because of hidden value.  I'm trying to write code that loops through all the form fields and manually grabs the value from cached object to handle the restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `InitalizeCache` to this

```
function InitalizeCache(key) {
  RecoverFormFromLocalStorage(key);
}
```

Rename `RecoverFormFromLocalStorage2` to `populateDataFromLocalStorage` and change to this

```
function populateDataFromLocalStorage(key) {
  var cache = localStorage.getItem(key);

  if (cache !== null) {
    var formJson = JSON.parse(cache);
    $("#application-form *").filter(':input').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('name');

      var formRecord = formJson.find(function(record) {
        return name === record.name;
      }) || {};

      if (this.type === "text") {
        $(this).val(formRecord.value);
      }

      if (this.type === "checkbox") {
        $(this).prop('checked', formRecord.value === 'true');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Update `LoadSpikeData()` to call the correct function name `populateDataFromLocalStorage`

Also the inputs at the end should have `type="button"`